# MIPS Address Explanation

Tags: assembly, mips

I am working on an assignment for school and part of this assignment is sorting through various MIPS instructions and determining if they act on constants or variables.  My question has to do with addresses.  I was reading through my textbook and I can't figure out if an address is considered a constant or a variable.  I want to say it's a variable but I can't really be too sure.  If someone could verify this for me that would be very helpful.

Comment: This is a pretty general question as phrased.  Do you have definitions for *constant* and *variable*?  These would help guide us to a useful answer.  In a non-Harvard architecture, all of memory is writeable and so in some sense "variable".  But from a program's point of view, there are "program sections" (psects) which are read only and others which are read/write.

Comment: So for example, the exact question is about the instruction "la" and the question states "Is the use of this instruction loading a constant or variable?"  I don't have any definitions other than that one.

Comment: Another question that I am interested in getting answered is does the format type of a pseudo instruction come from the format of the instructions that are being used "under the hood" for that pseudo?

Comment: What does "format type (of a pseudo instruction)" mean?

Comment: pseudo instructions are just a placeholder for real instructions, so just look at the real instructions.  I assume for constant you mean immediate encoded in the instruction, vs something that is not encoded in the instruction.  I want to load the number 5 into a register, I can use an instruction with the number 5 in the register or I can put the number 5 in memory somewhere, and the load the value from that address in memory.  the address itself is a number just like 5 and can be done with immediates or indirectly.  immediates are spelled out clearly in the instruction set reference manuals

Answer (score 1):

Well, given the usual frame of context for instructions in memory, one usually considers the instructions themselves to be constants, though one could write code which modifies them to a desired effect—which is occasionally used for some super-optimized purposes and also for viruses.  But given the normal case:

```
    .data
array1:     .space  12      # reserve 12 bytes for 3 integer array

    .text
__start:
        la   $t0, array1    # load array address
        li   $t1, 5         # $t1 = 5   ("load immediate")
        sw   $t1, ($t0)     # a[0] = 5
        li   $t1, 13        # $t1 = 13
        addi $t0, t0, 4     # t0 = t0 + 4
        sw   $t1, ($t0)     # a[1] = 13
        li   $t1, -7        # $t1 = -7
        sw   $t1, 4($t0)    # a[2] = -7
        done
```

So, in this sequence, the values 5, 13, and -7 are part of the instructions and would normally be considered constants.  Also, the 4 used to increment the address pointer in $t0 is also a constant.  Furthermore, the address of `array1` is constant *once the program is loaded into memory* in that it does not vary.  However, until the program loads, its address is *not* known:  the address assignments of both program sections (.data and .text) are assigned by the loader.

Comment: That helped a lot.  What I meant when I was asking about the format type of a pseudo instruction is that some instructions like lw or sw are I format while others such as add are R format.  So what is the format for a pseudo instruction?

Comment: @Samuel:  So a pseudo instruction like `.text` or `.space`?

Comment: Here is a list of pseudo instructions https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Pseudoinstructions

Comment: @Samuel:  Most of those are `macro` instructions as most other assembly languages term them.  They are convenience aliases which look and work like native instructions on (or inspired by) other architectures.  The usual definition of a pseudo instruction is an instruction which tells the assembler to do something but does not correspond to a machine instruction.